# FATAL: Unable to initialize the API: disconnected from wss://1rpc.io/dot: 1006:: Abnormal Closure

Tags: polkadot-js, wallet

I am trying to access my polkadot.js wallet, but keep recieving this messagge:FATAL:

Unable to initialize the API: disconnected from wss://1rpc.io/dot: 1006:: Abnormal Closure

I cannot connect wallet extension with any of the pages I have DOT delegated.

Could give any advise on how to solve this problem?? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with your network or the service provider(1RPC).

Feel free to test other endpoints and see if they work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have anything in your browser blocking the conexion, for example uBlock. See this issue FATAL: [Unable to initialize the API: disconnected from wss://pub.elara.patract.io/kusama: 1006:: Abnormal Closure #3960](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/3960)

Another good resource you can take a look is this guide [Polkadot-JS UI: How to Troubleshoot Connection Issues](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000176918-polkadot-js-ui-how-to-troubleshoot-connection-issues)